# how to set a max-height for a css grid row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a max-height of `40px` to the second row of a CSS Grid.
The width of the container is unknown therefore it should be responsive.
Also the content of each box is unknown.

I tried `grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0, 40px);` but unfortunately it will also set a height of 40px if no second row exists.

Is there any way to use `grid-template-rows` and prevent the second row from growing to `40px`?

Here is an example where you can see that the second row takes space although there are no grid items:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(95px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0, 40px);
  grid-auto-rows: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}


body {
 width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F">Colors</a></h1>

<ul>
  <li>Android green</li>
  <li>Antique brass</li>
  <li>Antique bronze</li>
  <li>Antique fuchsia</li>
  <li>Antique ruby</li>
  <li>Antique white</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current `grid` implementation for `minmax` is always using the larger value. (See [minmax() defaulting to max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50666794/159319))

Therefore `minmax(0, 40px)` will always result in `40px`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows) property to define the height of *implicitly* created grid rows.

In your case, you'll define your grid as having only one row. Then any additional grid rows created by your content will use the dimensions defined with the `grid-auto-rows` property. This way the second row won't exist until it's needed.

Edit: To have only one row display by default, but also define a height of 40px for a second row if needed, *AND* define a height of 15px for third, fourth, fifth rows if needed, you can add multiple values to `grid-auto-rows`.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(95px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 40px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
body {
 width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F">Colors</a></h1>

<ul>
  <li>Android green</li>
  <li>Antique brass</li>
  <li>Antique bronze</li>
  <li>Antique fuchsia</li>
  <li>Antique ruby</li>
  <li>Antique white</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not sure why this answer was downvoted but this won’t help me as it will style all upcoming rows not only the second row

Comment: @jantimon It sounded like you were only planning to have two rows. I'm also not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: @jantimon What size should the 3rd, 4th, etc rows be?

Comment: All other rows should be of height `0`

Comment: @jantimon why do you want rows with contents but no height?

Comment: I am using it for a responsive show more button: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-joliot-d55tw?file=/src/ShowMoreGrid.tsx

Comment: @jantimon That's helpful context. Setting a row's height to 0 is not an accessible way to hide content. It will still be focusable by keyboard and assistive tech users. Regardless, moving the "show more" button out of the grid will simplify things greatly in your example.

Comment: why does accessibility matter for this question? :)
btw my demo is accessible try to use the tab key

Comment: your suggestion to always show a "show more" button leads to a bad ux as soon as all items fit in one row

Comment: if it helps to understand the question assume that all following rows should have a height of 15px..

Comment: @jantimon [Accessibility matters for all digital interfaces](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/). If you can tab to things that aren't visible, it's not accessible. I'm not following how it would lead to bad user experience.

Comment: @jantimon I've edited the question to have an auto first row, 40px second row (if needed), 15px subsequent rows (if needed).